# Asigning values to a list using certain parameters in Excel

Tags: excel

I'm new here. I was wondering if someone could help me simplify the way I assign a type of value to a list of products, maybe with some macro which I'm really not an expert at.

For now what I have are two tables:

- Table 1: has details on what type of product is being manufactured. It has a name (ID), description (Tipico), Qty of connections (puntas), and amount of hours used to manufacture each product (Hs estimadas)

[image: Table 1]

- Table 2: has specific information about each individual product that is currently being manufactured, so people will complete the specific amount of connections (puntas) each product will require an this assigns a certain type of product (in column "Tipico") considering the parameters defined on table 1, for example:

[image: Table2]

To do this I have created this simple IF / AND / OR function in excel, but I find it too long, too messy and really difficult to correct or add new typical products when needed:

```
=IF(AND(OR([@Area]="PROTECCIÓN";[@Area]="CONTROL");RIGHT([@Tablero];3)<>"RTU";[@Area]<>"DAG";AND([@[Cant. Puntas]]>40;[@[Cant. Puntas]]<800));"TIPICO 1";IF(AND(OR([@Area]="PROTECCIÓN";[@Area]="CONTROL");RIGHT([@Tablero];3)<>"RTU";[@Area]<>"DAG";AND([@[Cant. Puntas]]>800;[@[Cant. Puntas]]<1200));"TIPICO 2";IF(AND(OR([@Area]="PROTECCIÓN";[@Area]="CONTROL");RIGHT([@Tablero];3)<>"RTU";[@Area]<>"DAG";AND([@[Cant. Puntas]]>1200;[@[Cant. Puntas]]<1600));"TIPICO 3";IF(AND(OR([@Area]="PROTECCIÓN";[@Area]="CONTROL");RIGHT([@Tablero];3)<>"RTU";[@Area]<>"DAG";AND([@[Cant. Puntas]]>1600;[@[Cant. Puntas]]<2000));"TIPICO 4";IF(AND(OR([@Area]="PROTECCIÓN";[@Area]="CONTROL");RIGHT([@Tablero];3)<>"RTU";[@Area]<>"DAG";AND([@[Cant. Puntas]]>2000;[@[Cant. Puntas]]<2400));"TIPICO 5";IF(AND([@Area]="COMUNICACIONES";LEFT([@Tablero];14)="TABLERO ETL600");"TIPICO 6";IF(AND([@Area]="COMUNICACIONES";OR(LEFT([@Tablero];11)="TABLERO FOX";LEFT([@Tablero];11)="TABLERO NSD570";LEFT([@Tablero];15)="TABLERO CENTRAL"));"TIPICO 7";IF(AND([@Area]="CONTROL";RIGHT([@Tablero];3)="RTU");"TIPICO 8";IF(AND([@Area]="DAG";AND([@[Cant. Puntas]]>0;[@[Cant. Puntas]]<=900));"TIPICO 9";IF(AND([@Area]="DAG";AND([@[Cant. Puntas]]>900;[@[Cant. Puntas]]<=1200));"TIPICO 10";IF(AND([@Area]="DAG";AND([@[Cant. Puntas]]>1200;[@[Cant. Puntas]]<=1600));"TIPICO 11";IF(AND([@Area]="CONTROL";RIGHT([@Tablero];4)="TIOR");"TIPICO 12";IF(AND([@Area]="CONTROL";H662OR(RIGHT([@Tablero];8)="IEC61850";RIGHT([@Tablero];9)="OPERACIÓN"));"TIPICO 13";"")))))))))))))
```

Is it possible to do this any other way?

Any ideas will be much appreciated!

Thanks to everyone